# Retrieve value from different fields for each record of an Access table

Tags: sql, string, ms-access, ms-access-2010, eval

I would be more than appreciative for some help here, as I have been having some serious problems with this.

**Background:**

I have a list of unique records.  For each record I have a monotonically increasing pattern (either A, B or C), and a development position (1 to 5) assigned to it.

So each of the 3 patterns is set out in five fields representing the development period.

**Problem:**

I need to retrieve the percentages relating to the relevant development periods, from different fields for each row.  It should be in a single column called "Output".

**Example:**

Apologies, not sure how to attach a table here, but the fields are below, the table is a transpose of these fields.

```
ID - (1,2,3,4,5)
Pattern - (A, B, C, A, C)
Dev - (1,5,3,4,2)
1 - (20%, 15%, 25%, 20%, 25%)
2 - (40%, 35%, 40%, 40%, 40%)
3 - (60%, 65%, 60%, 60%, 60%)
4 - (80%, 85%, 65%, 80%, 65%)
5 - (100%, 100%, 100%, 100%, 100%)
Output - (20%, 100%, 60%, 80%, 40%)
```

In MS Excel, I could simply use a HLOOKUP or OFFSET function to do this.  But how do I do this in Access?  The best I have come up with so far is Output: Eval([Category]) but this doesn't seem to achieve what I want which is to select the "Dev" field, and treat this as a field when building an expression.

In practice, I have more than 100 development periods to play with, and over 800 different patterns, so "switch" methods can't work here I think.

Thanks in advance,
alch84

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag since your question has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: To post sample data: http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: So you have two tables? The patterns belong in a separate table but I'm not clear about your database.

Comment: Ultimately this is probably a simple join (or subquery). If I understood the relationship and column name better I would post a query.

Comment: Hi @shawnt00, thanks for your response.  Gord Thompson's table below is an appropriate reflection of what I'm trying to do, and his suggested query below sort of does the trick, but the issue is a lack of primary key (possibly because I'm using a linked Excel table?).  So the multiple condition argument doesn't quite work for me...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that

1. [ID] is a unique column (primary key), and
2. the source column for [Output] only depends on the value of [Dev]

then this seems to work:

```sql
UPDATE tblAlvo SET Output = DLOOKUP("[" & Dev & "]", "tblAlvo", "ID=" & ID)
```

Before:

```
ID  Pattern  Dev  1   2   3   4   5    Output
--  -------  ---  --  --  --  --  ---  ------
 1  A          1  20  40  60  80  100
 2  B          5  15  35  65  85  100
 3  C          3  25  40  60  65  100
 4  A          4  20  40  60  80  100
 5  C          2  25  40  60  65  100
```

After:

```
ID  Pattern  Dev  1   2   3   4   5    Output
--  -------  ---  --  --  --  --  ---  ------
 1  A          1  20  40  60  80  100      20
 2  B          5  15  35  65  85  100     100
 3  C          3  25  40  60  65  100      60
 4  A          4  20  40  60  80  100      80
 5  C          2  25  40  60  65  100      40
```

Comment: Thanks Gord - looks good but what if I haven't got a primary key? Bad practice I know, but my Access tables are imported from an Excel workbook which doesn't have a primary key.

Comment: If `(ID, Pattern, Dev)` uniquely identifies rows then you could add those to the WHERE argument of the DLOOKUP (third parameter, `"ID=" & ID & " AND Pattern='" & Pattern & ...`). Otherwise, you could have the import from Excel create an AutoNumber primary key column for you.

Comment: Thanks @GordThompson.  
1. This formula ran but gives "#Error!" down the field. 
`Dlookup("[" & [Dev] & "]", "tblAlvo", "C Lob=" & [C Lob] " AND P Item = " & [P Item] & " AND Year = " AND [Year])`.

2. Import from Excel didn't allow me to create an AutoNumber primary key column (at least because I'm linking directly to the data source using a linked table).

Comment: (1) Your DLookup example does not match the fields in your question. (2) Your third argument is missing `&` operators and is therefore syntactically incorrect. (3) `"C Lob=" & [C Lob] ...` won't work, it needs to be `"[C Lob]=" & [C Lob] ...` (4) If any of the fields are text fields then they need `'` delimiters around the text values. (5) "Importing from Excel" and "Linking to Excel" mean different things. Please edit your question to show what you are really doing.